# Where are Run configurations stored?

Tags: eclipse, macos, liclipse

I'm running Liclipse 2.5.3 on Mac OS. I renamed my project causing me to lose all my run configurations. When I tried recreating one, it says the file exists. However, there are no run configurations present.

Where are the run configs stored?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The normal location for launches is in the workspace in the

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches
```

folder.

Each launch configuration is in a separate xxx.launch file which is a xml  file.

You can also Export and Import launch configurations.

Comment: When i renamed my projects, i lost view of these in the GUI, I just deleted them so I could rename them to the prior run configurations. Probably because each of the launch configs had a pointer to the workspace.  like this    <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/My_stuff/shell.sh"/>

Comment: This is still valid for `Eclipse v2019.3`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

These configrations are located in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches`, and they are `*.launch` files.

Note that each `workspace` has its own `.metadata` folder.

Answer (score 2):

@greg-449's answer tells you where they are stored, but you might be running into a situation where the launch configs for the renamed project are just being filtered/hidden. In the Launch Configurations dialog, there is a toolbar button to control filtering. Check there if deleted/unavailable projects are being filtered; if so try disabling that option and see if your missing configs come back into view.

[image]

Comment: This was my exact problem, thank you!