# How do I clear out old classes when exporting a java project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, export, settings

I am writing a java program using an IDE called Eclipse. When I go to export the program, select runnable jar file, and click 'Next', at the top of the exporting window, there is a dropdown input box as seen labelled 'Launch configuration', as seen in this image.

[image]

When I click on this to choose the correct main class, a list of Main classes pop up, including a large amount of old main classes from previously deleted projects, as seen here:

[image]

Is there a way to configure this so Eclipse only displays a list of the main classes that are being used in current projects, as opposed to a mix of currently used and old main classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the 'Run > Run Configurations' menu. The dialog that appears contains all the 'launch configurations' that Eclipse currently has. You can delete them here (or rename them to something more useful).

Comment: Thanks for your response! There were only about 5 unused main classes in the location you specified that I deleted, but there are still a lot of old Main classes listed. Do you know how to completely clear out all of them apart from the used classes?

Comment: Possibly it is picking up old stuff still in the run configuration metadata location - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36652933/2670892)

Comment: In the workspace. Folders starting with . are hidden by Finder, use ⇧⌘. to show them (shift + command + '.')